# algorithm for determining best hotel for particular price

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pseudocode, linear-programming

I am developing a trip advising application which determines the optimum traveling options for travelers such as the transportation method, accommodation type under a particular budget amount. I am trying to develop a algorithm for determine the best room, a tourist can take during his/her journey for a particular price among a range of hotels. hotels may have normal, luxury and super-luxury rooms for different prices for each. I want to get the best facility for a particular amount of money. Can anyone give me an idea to develop this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real answer to this, because weighting comfort against price is highly subjective. One person might want to best price possible where the only condition is that the room is clean, while others might want to travel light and will pay an extra for additional towels etc..

You'll need to find a way to adjust weights of your objective function based on an individuals preferences, but this task is beyond linear programming.